# Prepare image for classification in Dart using TFlite v2

Tags: python, dart, tensorflow

I have a TFlite model which I would like to use in a Flutter app, I decided to use the package [tflite_v2](https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_v2) since it seemed the easiest. I wrote a short python program to test the model first and make sure it gives the correct result:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf

tflite_model_path = 'efficientnetb3-Eye Disease-95.26.tflite'

class_labels = {
    0: 'cataract',
    1: 'diabetic_retinopathy',
    2: 'glaucoma',
    3: 'normal'
}

def load_and_preprocess_image(image_path):
  img = cv2.imread(image_path)
  img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
  img = cv2.resize(img, (224, 224))
  img = img.astype(np.float32) / 1.0

  # Add an extra dimension for the batch (if the model expects batches)
  img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
  return img


interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=tflite_model_path)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

test_image = load_and_preprocess_image('dataset/normal/2702_left.jpg')
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], test_image)
interpreter.invoke()

output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
print(output_data)

predicted_class_index = np.argmax(output_data[0])

print(f"Predicted class: {predicted_class_index} ({class_labels[predicted_class_index]})")
```

I am having trouble recreating exactly what the `load_and_preprocess_image` function does in dart, and so the model is giving me wrong answers.

Here is a function I found in the package doc which converts images into binary list using the image package

```
Uint8List imageToByteListFloat32(
    img.Image image, int inputSize, double mean, double std) {
  var convertedBytes = Float32List(1 * inputSize * inputSize * 3);
  var buffer = Float32List.view(convertedBytes.buffer);
  int pixelIndex = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < inputSize; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < inputSize; j++) {
      var pixel = image.getPixel(j, i);
      buffer[pixelIndex++] = (img.getRed(pixel) - mean) / std;
      buffer[pixelIndex++] = (img.getGreen(pixel) - mean) / std;
      buffer[pixelIndex++] = (img.getBlue(pixel) - mean) / std;
    }
  }
  return convertedBytes.buffer.asUint8List();
}
```

Problem with this is it seems outdated as there are no such functions as `getRed`, `getGreen`, or `getBlue`.